# How to use capybara in rspec to click on a link in the navbar?

Tags: rspec, capybara, navbar

I have this code

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'planets features' do
  describe 'adding a new planet' do
    it 'adds a planet to the list of planets' do
      visit planets_path
      click_link('List your planet')

      expect(current_path).to have_content('/planets/new')

      fill_in('Name', with: 'Test')
      click_button('Publish')

      expect(current_path).to have_content('/planets')
      expect(page).to have_content('Test')

    end
  end
end
```

It shows this error in the terminal:

> planets features adding a new planet adds a planet to the list of
> planets
> Failure/Error: click_link('List your planet')
>
> ```
>  Capybara::ElementNotFound:
>    Unable to find link "List your planet"
> ```

```
The link I want to click is in the navbar.
Here is a part of the code in the navbar with the link 'List your planet'.

<div class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light navbar-lewagon">
  <%= link_to planets_path, class: "navbar-brand" do %>
    <p class="navbar-logo"><i class="fas fa-meteor"></i> PIANETA</p>
    <% end %>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>


  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <% if user_signed_in? %>

        <%= link_to "List your planet", new_planet_path, class: "btn btn-outline-primary-1 shadow-none focus-none text-decoration-none", type: "button", role: "button" %>
        <%= link_to "My Listings", planets_path, class: "btn btn-outline-primary-1 shadow-none focus-none text-decoration-none", type: "button", role: "button" %>
```

How do I write the test correctly, so that it finds the link in the navbar ?

Answer (score 0):

To me it doesn't look like a link but a button instead (based on the class name and type).

Try `click_button('List your planet')` instead

If that doesn't work try `find('.btn', :text => 'List your planet').click`

Answer (score 0):

your navbar has a piece of code that only display "List your Planet" if the users is logged in.

Reference:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
```

You need to instruct your test to perform a login operation before you visit that url.